# What is the difference between @$_POST vs $_POST....?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I was looking at different ways to save a user's input in a form after they refresh the browser and I came across this:

```
value="<?php echo @$_POST['blah'];?>">
```

and I have also seen it like the following:

```
value="<?php echo $_POST['blah'];?>">
```

They both appear to do the same thing. What is the significance of the @ sign prepended to the $_POST array? Is one way preferred over the other?

Comment: It is called an "at sign" so now you can search the net for it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@` is PHP's [error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).  Basically, putting it before an expression (such as an array access or a function call) will suppress any errors that would normally be generated.  Functionally, there's no difference, it's just in what warnings/notices will be generated and logged or displayed, depending on your settings.

In this case, if `'blah'` is not defined in the $_POST array, the first form (with the @) won't generate a notice, whereas the second form will.

As for what's preferred, in my experience `@` is generally discouraged, as is anything that just suppresses errors - better practice is to be proactive about checking for things first.  Among other reasons, the PHP docs give this reason to be wary of it:

> Warning: Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even disable error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no indication as to why.

**TL;DR:** It suppresses errors, which is generally discouraged unless you have a good reason to do so.  Better to be proactive.

Answer (score 3):

The `@` sign surpresses any errors thrown by the POST. For example, when its undefined, you wont receive a warning.

Comment: That's why I disable annoying warnings that don't tell me anything.

Answer (score 2):

In Php when placing the @ is to prevent show us system errors that we have in that portion of code.